Python poetry has lost dependencies and is using the wrong version of python
I've been using Python Poetry for the past few weeks.  When I want back to a project and started poetry shell and tried to execute it it failed because it could not find its dependencies.  Running poetry show showed that the missing module (lnagchain-anthropic) had been installed.  After doing a poetry update it gave a slightly different error regarding dependencies.  When I did a poetry show requests it first showed a warning that it was using an older version of python, but then showed that is was configured to use Python 3.12.5 which is correct.
Here's my CLI and stack trace.  What could cause this error?
$ poetry shell
Spawning shell within /home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12
$ . /home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/bin/activate
(agents-py3.12) $ python agents.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dean/src/ai/langchain/examples/langchain-tutorials/agents/agents.py", line 4, in <module>
    from langchain_anthropic import ChatAnthropic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain_anthropic'

(agents-py3.12) $ poetry show
aiohappyeyeballs         2.4.0    Happy Eyeballs for asyncio
aiohttp                  3.10.5   Async http client/server framework (asyncio)
aiosignal                1.3.1    aiosignal: a list of registered asynchron...
annotated-types          0.7.0    Reusable constraint types to use with typ...
anthropic                0.34.1   The official Python library for the anthr...
anyio                    4.4.0    High level compatibility layer for multip...
attrs                    24.2.0   Classes Without Boilerplate
certifi                  2024.7.4 Python package for providing Mozilla's CA...
charset-normalizer       3.3.2    The Real First Universal Charset Detector...
dataclasses-json         0.6.7    Easily serialize dataclasses to and from ...
defusedxml               0.7.1    XML bomb protection for Python stdlib mod...
distro                   1.9.0    Distro - an OS platform information API
filelock                 3.15.4   A platform independent file lock.
frozenlist               1.4.1    A list-like structure which implements co...
fsspec                   2024.6.1 File-system specification
greenlet                 3.0.3    Lightweight in-process concurrent program...
h11                      0.14.0   A pure-Python, bring-your-own-I/O impleme...
httpcore                 1.0.5    A minimal low-level HTTP client.
httpx                    0.27.0   The next generation HTTP client.
huggingface-hub          0.24.6   Client library to download and publish mo...
idna                     3.7      Internationalized Domain Names in Applica...
jiter                    0.5.0    Fast iterable JSON parser.
jsonpatch                1.33     Apply JSON-Patches (RFC 6902)
jsonpointer              3.0.0    Identify specific nodes in a JSON documen...
langchain                0.2.14   Building applications with LLMs through c...
langchain-anthropic      0.1.23   An integration package connecting Anthrop...
langchain-community      0.2.12   Community contributed LangChain integrati...
langchain-core           0.2.34   Building applications with LLMs through c...
langchain-text-splitters 0.2.2    LangChain text splitting utilities
langgraph                0.2.10   Building stateful, multi-actor applicatio...
langgraph-checkpoint     1.0.3    Library with base interfaces for LangGrap...
langsmith                0.1.101  Client library to connect to the LangSmit...
marshmallow              3.22.0   A lightweight library for converting comp...
multidict                6.0.5    multidict implementation
mypy-extensions          1.0.0    Type system extensions for programs check...
numpy                    1.26.4   Fundamental package for array computing i...
orjson                   3.10.7   Fast, correct Python JSON library support...
packaging                24.1     Core utilities for Python packages
pydantic                 2.8.2    Data validation using Python type hints
pydantic-core            2.20.1   Core functionality for Pydantic validatio...
pyyaml                   6.0.2    YAML parser and emitter for Python
requests                 2.32.3   Python HTTP for Humans.
sniffio                  1.3.1    Sniff out which async library your code i...
sqlalchemy               2.0.32   Database Abstraction Library
tenacity                 8.5.0    Retry code until it succeeds
tokenizers               0.20.0   
tqdm                     4.66.5   Fast, Extensible Progress Meter
typing-extensions        4.12.2   Backported and Experimental Type Hints fo...
typing-inspect           0.9.0    Runtime inspection utilities for typing m...
urllib3                  2.2.2    HTTP library with thread-safe connection ...
yarl                     1.9.4    Yet another URL library

(agents-py3.12) $ which python
/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/bin/python

(agents-py3.12) $ poetry update
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (3.9s)

Package operations: 51 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing certifi (2024.8.30)
  - Installing h11 (0.14.0)
  - Installing idna (3.8)
  - Installing sniffio (1.3.1)
  - Installing typing-extensions (4.12.2)
  - Installing annotated-types (0.7.0)
  - Installing anyio (4.4.0)
  - Installing charset-normalizer (3.3.2)
  - Installing httpcore (1.0.5)
  - Installing pydantic-core (2.20.1)
  - Installing urllib3 (2.2.2)
  - Installing httpx (0.27.2)
  - Installing jsonpointer (3.0.0)
  - Installing orjson (3.10.7)
  - Installing pydantic (2.8.2)
  - Installing requests (2.32.3)
  - Installing filelock (3.15.4)
  - Installing frozenlist (1.4.1)
  - Installing fsspec (2024.6.1)
  - Installing jsonpatch (1.33)
  - Installing langsmith (0.1.107)
  - Installing multidict (6.0.5)
  - Installing packaging (24.1)
  - Installing pyyaml (6.0.2)
  - Installing tenacity (8.5.0)
  - Installing tqdm (4.66.5)
  - Installing aiohappyeyeballs (2.4.0)
  - Installing aiosignal (1.3.1)
  - Installing attrs (24.2.0)
  - Installing greenlet (3.0.3)
  - Installing huggingface-hub (0.24.6)
  - Installing langchain-core (0.2.36)
  - Installing mypy-extensions (1.0.0)
  - Installing yarl (1.9.4)
  - Installing aiohttp (3.10.5)
  - Installing distro (1.9.0)
  - Installing jiter (0.5.0)
  - Installing langchain-text-splitters (0.2.2)
  - Installing marshmallow (3.22.0)
  - Installing numpy (1.26.4)
  - Installing sqlalchemy (2.0.32)
  - Installing tokenizers (0.20.0)
  - Installing typing-inspect (0.9.0)
  - Installing anthropic (0.34.1)
  - Installing dataclasses-json (0.6.7)
  - Installing defusedxml (0.7.1)
  - Installing langchain (0.2.15)
  - Installing langgraph-checkpoint (1.0.6)
  - Installing langchain-anthropic (0.1.23)
  - Installing langchain-community (0.2.14)
  - Installing langgraph (0.2.14)

Writing lock file

(agents-py3.12) $ python agents.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dean/src/ai/langchain/examples/langchain-tutorials/agents/agents.py", line 4, in <module>
    from langchain_anthropic import ChatAnthropic
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_anthropic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_anthropic/chat_models.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/callbacks/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from langchain_core.callbacks.file import FileCallbackHandler
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/callbacks/file.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain_core.agents import AgentAction, AgentFinish
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/agents.py", line 31, in <module>
    from langchain_core.messages import (
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/messages/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from langchain_core.messages.ai import (
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/messages/ai.py", line 6, in <module>
    from langchain_core.messages.base import (
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/messages/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from langchain_core.utils import get_bolded_text
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/utils/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from langchain_core.utils.utils import (
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_core/utils/utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    from requests import HTTPError, Response
  File "/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.api'

(agents-py3.12) $ poetry show requests
The currently activated Python version 3.10.12 is not supported by the project (^3.12).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3.12 (3.12.5)
Creating virtualenv agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12 in /home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
 name         : requests                
 version      : 2.32.3                  
 description  : Python HTTP for Humans. 

dependencies
 - certifi >=2017.4.17
 - charset-normalizer >=2,<4
 - idna >=2.5,<4
 - urllib3 >=1.21.1,<3

required by
 - huggingface-hub *
 - langchain >=2,<3
 - langchain-community >=2,<3
 - langsmith >=2,<3

(agents-py3.12) $ which python
/home/dean/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/agents-9r0AuBgK-py3.12/bin/python
(agents-py3.12) $ 
(agents-py3.12) $ python --version
Python 3.12.5
((agents-py3.12) $ 


Looks like maybe something went wrong at some point and the virtual environment is in a corrupt state. If I were you I would recreate the virtual environments from scratch.
